# Referencing javascript files on my local machine

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I know that its possible to reference third party JavaScript files on the web like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to reference javaScript file on my local machine by doing something like this?

```
<script src="file:///C:/folder/custom_javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I suspect this may be a no-no, since it could be a way for websites to find out what files are on a client's computer...

The reason I would like to do this is because I am developing a javaScript-heavy application on google app engine.  I'd like to be able to run and debug revisions to my javaScript files without having to re-upload them every time I make a change.  Currently, every time I change something in the javascript, I have to:

1. Go into the HTML file that I am using to run the javaScript and change a revision variable at the end of the filename so that the old version is not cached somewhere: `<script src="resource/custom/js/the_file_im_working_with.js?revision=76" type="text/javascript"></script>`
2. Upload the entire application to google app engine
3. Change a variable at the end of the url that I am loading in my browser window so that I don't get a cached version of THAT file holding a reference to the cached version of the OTHER javascript file: `https://my_app.appspot.com/index.html?revision=26`
4. Re-set any break points in the Firefox debugger because now Firefox thinks its dealing with a different file since the "revision" variable is different.

The result of all this is my concentration being broken and wasted time.

I tried playing around with caching options in the HTML headers and in the browser itself, but I think the files may be being cached by a server somewhere between google and my computer.

Any input or ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot reference a local file from a non-local file. The closest workaround would be to set up a local server on your machine and link to `localhost`:

```
<script src="http://localhost/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: I suspected this might be the case.  I apologize that this may be an obnoxious question: is there an "easy" server that can be set up on my machine?  By "easy", I mean something that I can install and configure without having to know a lot of stuff.  I can see this being one of those things that *should* take 15 minutes, but ends up consuming a whole day of frustration due to me not knowing what I'm doing.

Comment: @DutrowLLC: There are lots of really "easy" servers - Uniserver and XAMPP are two popular ones that come to mind.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  I used Uniserver.  It was pretty easy to set up on Windows Vista.  I used a symbolic link to make the javaScript source code available from Uniserver's "www" folder.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a whole new deploy of your app for every little change seems like a way too much trouble.

You should attempt to develop the app locally. I guess you are doing all this because you are very bound to the App Engine. But you should at least be able to develop the frontend stuff locally.

Comment: I should have specified in the question that I can not develop locally because I'm interacting with a giant database on App Engine.  I definitely wish that were an option though.

Answer (score 1):

Points 1,3 and 4 are all solved by [holding down the SHIFT key and reloading the page (or CTRL + F5)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBypass_your_cache). This tells Firefox and all intervening caches that you want a fresh copy of the HTML and all linked resources.

Comment: I did not know about the SHIFT key thing.  I did set the browser to never cache files.  Is that not the same thing?

Comment: Maybe. I do know for a fact that when you shift-reload the browser sends a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header with the request and all HTTP/1.1 proxies that get this header are supposed to refetch the original resource. Telling the browser not to cache may not necessarily send this header.

Comment: Alright so I tried this out.  Unfortunately, it does not work.  Sometimes the revised version is loaded immediately after doing this.  However, other times, I keep pressing CTRL+F5 and the old version keeps coming up.  My theory is that some of the servers relaying the request are not obeying the caching directives.

Comment: Try installing Live HTTP Headers Addon and test that theory. The addon will show you times, etags, status etc for each request and response.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reference the file in a relative way, like so: 
`<script src="scripts/chart.min.js"></script>`