# Is there a way to read all .jpg filenames from a folder using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, p5.js

I'm creating a local index.html file which needs to display all images from a local folder. This folder is getting a new image stored into it every few minutes using Processing. My goal is to place the latest image of that folder into the HTML file (running locally on Chrome).

Comment: You mean without a server? Just the html file?

Comment: no, there is not without some sort of http server

Comment: You can't scan folders from JavaScript running in the browser, local file or not.

Comment: I really doubt, even using things like `fileReader`, that any browser would allow code searching the user's local files.

Comment: as a quick and dirty solution, I'd use something like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) to host the index.html and run a little script in node that [watches the folder](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher) and [updates the html file](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback). The file watcher is easily googled together and using serve saves me the hassle to even look how to set up a server in node let alone refresh the page on update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing javascript files on my local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356165/referencing-javascript-files-on-my-local-machine)

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to javascript running inside the browser, then no. The browser is running the scripts in a sandbox type of environment, without direct connection to the file system.

To do that you need javascript running as a server (nodejs), but I think that is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: This is no longer true, since some browsers support the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).

Answer (score -1):

If you have control over the file names going into the folder, you could create a jquery script which loops through the directory links to potential images.

Then it adds the images accordingly to the page.

It then removes the ones in which aren't their.

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { 
  jQuery('body').append('<img src="yourlocationhere/'+ i +'.png"/>');
    jQuery('img').error(function() {
        jQuery(this).remove();
    });
}
```

This is presuming your images are numbered between a range of numbers

Comment: You can reference a file locally on your machine, instead of on a server. Such as below:

        <img src="../img/testimg.png"/>

Comment: Of course you can locally reference a file using jQuery.
Just tried it on my machine to verify. 
This page is only being accessed locally, so im not sure what security risk there is really if its not actually being hosted anywhere?

Both files here are being hosted on their machine, not a server

Comment: if you have a html file with a javascript file within, you can reference a file within the same folder regardless of where this folder is. Look up relative referencing.

Comment: your point above, is talking about referencing a local file from a non local place. This scenario above is referencing a local file from a local place.

Comment: has anyone tried this method yet?